# How to access docker containers on wsl 2

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I am having Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running on wsl 2. I have installed docker according to this guide https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/. I have a stack with few services (basically I want to set up an environment to test my services before pushing to prod), the stack is running as expected on production, there are portainer and RabbitMq running on it and they are accessible on the network.

However, when I deploy the same stack (via docker-compose.yml) on the docker that I have installed on the ubuntu on wsl 2 **I can not access the RabbitMq and the Portainer services using localhost/127.0.0.1:<the published port/s>**. The containers are running stable from what I see with "docker container ls".

I have tried to set an inbound rules in the firewall - nop luck.

Here is the whole service setup from the docker-compose.yml:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: 3
        max-size: 5m
    hostname: rabbitmq
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 200M
        reservations:
          memory: 199M
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - webnet
```

Comment: why not ssh into the container and see if the setup is fine, you can also try some curl command to see if the service is running as expected

Comment: I can curl the localhost:<port> form the ubuntu itself. And as I mentioned, the compose is already tested and working fine on prod, so the services are running as they should. 

It seems as a mapping issue between windows and the wsl.

Comment: I have docker for windows installed on my machine (i.e. installed in Windows not in Ubuntu). It can be accessed from within WSL2 almost as if it were installed locally.

Comment: Good for you. Thanks for reviewing this question.

Comment: can you show the error, also can you show how you are doing the port mapping? also, I guess you made sure that the port you are exposing and port you are mapping is same

Comment: There is no error. It just times out when trying to reach the localhost:15672. I got both ports allowed by inbound rune in win firewall, and yet it cannot be reached. I have curled the localhost from the bash, and that works as expected, but it never loads from chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright, it turns out that I should have used the ip of the eth0 interface. Now I can access the services form the host/win.

Just type `ipconfig` in the docker container:

(if it return "command not found" you can install it with: `sudo apt install net-tools`)

[image: ipconfig results]

Comment: Consider adding info on how to get the above info :)

Running `ifconfig` gives the above output.

If your distro doesn't have it, it can be installed with:

`sudo apt install net-tools`

Comment: You can also use `ip addr` to pull up interfaces if you do not have net-tools (IE `ifconfig`)

Comment: after getting inside the container by running `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`, i get not found when hitting **ifconfig**, **ipconfig** or **ip addr**. outside the container, when i hit ipconfig, i do get the result like shown in the above answer pic, and but when i hit the INETVALUE:PORT_EXPOSED in the browser of my windows machine, i am still gettin "this site can't be reached " could you please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: After the container is running successfully, stand in the WSL2 Ubuntu terminal opened in Windows run `ip addr`, find the entry for `eth0` (something like `2: eth0:`), take the `inet` address from there (e.g. `inet 172.18.174.48`) and use it in your Windows requests like `http://172.18.174.48:<port>`. The port is what you assigned on left side in `docker run -p 49160:8080`, `49160` in this case.
Or from Windows terminal run `wsl hostname -I` and use the first address shown.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way that I found for local development and testing is to enable the Docker WSL2 integration for my distro.
Then I can access the docker containers from within WSL2 directly: i.e. in WSL I can access my postgres database docker container via `localhost:5432`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your may also try to expose wsl ports to windows, using this script
https://gist.github.com/xmeng1/aae4b223e9ccc089911ee764928f5486

I have troubles while connecting to wsl via ssh, and manage to do it after using this

Answer (score 1):

You could get the WSL VM address via `wsl hostname -I` then use the first address shown instead of `localhost`.

Like

```bash
wsl hostname -I
// 172.18.174.48 172.17.0.1 172.19.0.1
```

Use `172.18.174.48`.

Answer (score 0):

With WSL 2 the linux system uses a virtual network adapter.

Check the network address with (/sbin/) ifconfig in Linux, search for eth0:

```
[root@MYLAPTOP docker]# ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:cb:30:8a:75  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
==>     inet 172.30.48.18  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.30.63.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fec6:439f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:c6:43:9f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 410228  bytes 27824856 (26.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 386628  bytes 1110476982 (1.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Then, forward the port, in windows, using netsh.

E.g. to expose the Web port (80):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=<windows-hostname-or-ip> connectport=80 connectaddress=
```